# Count ways to n'th stair(order does not matter)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

**There are N stairs, and a person standing at the bottom wants to reach the top. The person can climb either 1 stair or 2 stairs at a time. Count the number of ways, the person can reach the top (order does not matter).
Note: Order does not matter means for n=4 {1 2 1},{2 1 1},{1 1 2} are considered same.**

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-ways-to-nth-stairorder-does-not-matter/0

So I have been trying to solve this question and the problem I am facing is that I don't understand how do we solve questions like these where the order does not matter? I was able to solve the question when order mattered but I am not able to develop the logic to solve this.

This is the code I wrote for when order mattered

```
long int countWaysToStair(long int N)
{
    if(N == 1 || N == 2)
    return N;

    long int dp[N+1];

    dp[0] = 1;
    dp[1] = 1;

    dp[2] = 2;

    for(int i=3;i<=N;i++)
    {
      dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2];
    } 
    return dp[N];
}
```

Input:
4
Expected Output:
3
My output:
5

Comment: Good edit. But please turn the shown code into a [mre]. Add sample input (most easily perhaps as a hardcoded initialised array), the output (quote it separatly) you get and the output you expect when order does not matter. Also, just for readability, please consider applying a consistent indentation scheme, people here love that in shown code. ;-)

Comment: Is there a special reason for the function receiving an array? I get the impression that the result ca be calculated from `N` without an input array, a temp array and even without a loop....

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh I'm sorry I was actually trying memoization on this solution I'll just edit it ..U are right

Comment: There's one solution for every different number of 2-stairs-at-a-time. There's floor(N/2)+1 of these, so that's the answer.

Comment: I think your actual question "how do I solve questions of a particular type" is not easily answerable, since it requires knowledge of similar problems and some mathematical thought.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider that you have N stairs. First of all you have to understand if N is odd or even.

If is even than it will be a multiple of 2: N = 2*S, where S is the number of pair of stairs.

Suppose N = 6 and S = 3. Your first solution is {2,2,2}. than you can change the first 2 stairs with 1 + 1 stairs and you have your second solution {1, 1, 2 ,2}.
Since order doesn't matter let's proceed with the next pair and we have our third solution {1, 1, 1, 1, 2} and then the fourth {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Given N = 2*S the number of possible solutions are S + 1.

Now suppose N is odd and N = 2S + 1.
Let N = 7 and S = 3. Our solutions are {2,2,2,1}, {1,1,2,2,1}, {1,1,1,1,2,1} and {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}. Again, the number of solutions is given by S+1

Now your algorithm is pretty simple:

```
return N/2 + 1
```

Comment: Nice answer and you got my upvote. But allow me to make sure that you are aware of this concept, which I think can also be applied to users who do self learning or challenges: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Yunnosch this is nowhere related to homework. It is from a standard question bank.

Comment: So you did not get the part about "which I think can also be applied to users who do self learning or challenges", I take it?

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct, but if you want to know how DP is used in this problem, look at this example:

```
jumps =[1,2]
```

Lets say that `jump =1`, so for any stair, the number of ways will always be equal to `1`.

Now for `jump=2`, say for stair `8`:  no of ways will be (no of ways to reach 8 using 1 only)+(no of ways to reach 6 using both 1 and 2 because you can reach to 8 from 6 by just a jump of 2).

So the code will looks like:

```
 for(int i=1; i<=n;i++)
     dp[i]=1;

for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    dp[i]=dp[i]+dp[i-2];

return dp[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the order does not matter, ways to reach at the Nth place would be:
1 way:
1,1,1,1,1....... 1

remaining n/2 ways:
1,1,1,1,1.......2
1,1,1,1,1.....2,2
.
.
.
1,2,2,2,2,2,2...2,2,2   or 2,2,2,2,2,2,2....2 (depends whether n is even or odd).

we can safely say that ways to reach at the Nth place would be n/2 +1